Effort-Actuated Velocity Control in gz_ros_control?
I'm trying to port my old ROS1 stack to ROS2 (currently Ubuntu 22.04 running ROS2 Humble) and switch over to the new Gazebo Fortress simulator to test everything.
I'm trying to control a multi-legged robot and will be commanding joints' velocities on hardware, where servo-level PID controllers will handle conversion to actual torque outputs that aren't seen by the rest of the system. I'd like my Gazebo simulation to do something similar, but the position- and velocity-level controllers in Gazebo simply set the joints to desired positions or velocities without considering joint forces or effort limits. This "kinematic teleportation" is something that's been true for Gazebo Classic and its interfaces with both ROS1 and ROS2, but there have been workarounds:

ROS1 had interfaces like "effort_controllers/joint_position_controller" with tunable gains for PD/PID control that enabled joint effort simulation while still tracking a commanded position or velocity command.

ROS2's "gazebo_ros2_control" package for interfacing with Gazebo Classic eventually got PID-level control to command each joint's position or velocities.


However, I'm not seeing any similar ways of doing this in Gazebo Fortress or any of the control interfaces in the gz_ros2_control package. There don't seem to be any PID controllers available, and I can't find any examples of things like the joint_trajectory_controllers being used to do the thing I'm looking for.
Moving back to Gazebo Classic isn't an ideal solution for me--I've found that the new Gazebo's changes to the underlying dynamics engine play much nicer with multi-point force contacts and their associated force-torque sensor readings, which is good for the multi-legged, force-sensing robot system I'm trying to work with.
Is there a way to do this currently in gz_ros2_control? Am I missing something incredibly obvious or an example somewhere? Is this a feature I'll need to add manually? Thanks!!
(I know that gz_ros2_control and related packages are currently still named ign_ros2_control in Gazebo Fortress, which I'm using; I'm just keeping the name consistent with current documentation above for simplicity)

No this is currently not possible, but should be easy to be ported from gazebo_ros2_control.
Contributions are welcome, see this PR
